# Can Java NIO.2 read the ByteBuffer out of order?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nio

**For anyone interested, the answer to this questions is no, the socket wont read the buffer out of order.**

---

Is it possible for the AsynchronousSocketChannel to read bytes out of order? Im strugling to debug where my issue starts, my protocol serializes objects up to 32k and writes them to the socket like this:

```
AsynchronousSocketChannel socket; ...

// serialize packet

ByteBuffer base; // serialized buffer (unknown size, size growns as needed with limit of 32k)

for (int j1 = 0; j1 < 6 && base.remaining() > 0; j1++) { // limit to 6 tries

    socket.write(base).get(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (base.remaining() > 0) {
        // aparently, if the write operation could write everything at once, we wouldnt have an issue
    }
}
```

This write operation is not concurrent it is synchronized with locks. I use the standard read operation like this:

```
AsynchronousSocketChannel socket; ...

Future<Integer> reading = socket.read(getReadBuffer()); // the read buffer is 8k big

// consume the buffer also not concurrently
```

I can write up to 1000 packets per second with up to 1000 bytes each without issues, but eventually one or other client will break. If the packet is bigger, the frequency that it can handle without breaking will be lower, packets with 40.000 bytes will break if I write around 8 per second.

Example: I write 5 bytes (1,2,3,4,5), the buffer is big enough the write everything at once but the operation decides to stop with remaining bytes in the buffer (this should be the normal TCP behavior), so lets say the operation wrote 1,2,3, stopped and wrote the remain 4,5 (while buf.remain > 0 { write }), while reading, is most likely that I will read 4,5 first and 1,2,3 later, this should not happen.

While on localhost everything works fine, but just outside the same machine (still same network/routers) it wont work.

I do not flip the buffers to write/read. I can ensure its not an issue with the serialization and both the server and client are single-threaded. I'm forgetting to do something? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: The problem is in the code you didn't post.  Probably in the handling of the buffers between reads or writes.  One common bug, for example occurs when your read()  gets part of the next packet after the first one, and you fail to incorporate those bytes properly into the packet you read next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear why you're using asynchronous I/O if all you really want is synchronous I/O, which is what you are getting from that code. You'd be better off with an ordinary `SocketChannel`.

> I do not flip the buffers to write/read.

You must. You must `flip()` before `write()`, and `compact()` afterwards, where 'afterwards' in this case means the same as above.

Comment: Yes I am aware it is asynchronous, but I am testing the buffer after fetching the Future object, I just put it in one line because I dont need the return value of the `Future`.

About the flip, I **should** or I **must**? Can it work without flip?

Comment: @FurmigaHumana See edit. Of course you must flip. What problem do you have with implementing that?

Comment: After what you said I realized I wasn't fully aware on how to properly use the ByteBuffer. My issue was that I was writing the remaining parts in the wrong index.